# what is the point of set dev/null to standard out in a child process

Tags: c, linux, dup2

I saw this code in an application

```
 int dev_null_fd = open("/dev/null", "w");
 child_pid = fork()
 if (!child_pid) {
     dup2(dev_null_fd, 0);
     dup2(dev_null_fd, 1);   
     dup2(dev_null_fd, 2);
 }
```

What is the intention of this code? is it trying to discard stdin, stdout and stderr from the child process so that the messages are not mixed(polluted).

But, still, the messages from the child process are shown on the shell.

What is going on?

Thanks!

Comment: It kind of detaches the program from the terminal it was started from.

Comment: You might want to look into how demonization is done and how it drops the controlling terminal. Even if you redirect fds `0`,`1`,`2`, the controlling terminal remains to be readily around and accessible through `/dev/tty` unless you demonize. Or maybe just tell your child processes not to access the terminal directly.

Answer (score 0):

It's the equivalent of  `< /dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1` done in the shell.

It causes read/writes and other filedescriptor operations on filedescriptors `0`, `1`, and `2` to do nothing without returning an error, and it prevents future filedescriptor-allocating operations (`open`, `pipe`, `socket`, ...) from using filedescriptors `0`, `1`, and `2` for as long as these are kept open.